# How to avoid ORA-22992 error (select BLOBs through database link)

Tags: oracle, plsql

If you try to query a BLOB across a database link, exception ORA-22992 is triggered, saying that is not possible.

How to fix it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to create a local auxiliary table in your local database where the remote BLOBs will be stored.

While querying BLOBs across database links is not allowed, you can insert them into local tables:

`insert into local_table(id, blob_obj)
    (select remote.id, remote.blob_obj
     from   remote_table@remote_db remote);`